# Create a new collection from other collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Suposse I have a Collection like this:

```
{ "_id" : 8751, "title" : "The Banquet", "author" : "Dante" }
{ "_id" : 8752, "title" : "Divine Comedy", "author" : "Dante", "copies" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 8645, "title" : "Eclogues", "author" : "Dante" }
{ "_id" : 7000, "title" : "The Odyssey", "author" : "Homer", "copies" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 7020, "title" : "Iliad", "author" : "Homer", "copies" : 10 }
```

How can I generate a new collection with only the documents that have the field "copies", to get a new collection like this:

```
{ "_id" : 8752, "title" : "Divine Comedy", "author" : "Dante", "copies" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 7000, "title" : "The Odyssey", "author" : "Homer", "copies" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 7020, "title" : "Iliad", "author" : "Homer", "copies" : 10 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator to create a new collection based on aggregation results, try:

```
pipeline = [
    { $match: { copies: { $exists: true } } }
    { $out: "newCollectionName" }
]

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Comment: Should I run this in mongo shell? I am new on mongodb

Comment: you can run it either from mongo shell or directly from pymongo - it will just create a new collection (without any output)

Answer (score 0):

That didn't work for me using mongoshell, in my case I finally used:

```
cur = db.original_collection.find();
while (cur.hasNext()) { db.backup_collection.insert(cur.next()) }
```